# Which application to use for a calendar?

Tags: software-rec, linux-mint, calendar

I need a calendar that stores everything locally as I work from places that don't have internet sometimes (I'm a virtual office). I really can't figure it out from reading what I can find about the subject.  I am using Mint 12.

Comment: Lightning is working out very nicely for me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mozilla Thunderbird plus lightning addon (official replacement for Sunbird which is no longer actively maintained)

Comment: Yeah I tried this after following the link that @vicabreu gave us.  I don't use kde or gnome, so this is the best choice.

Comment: Mozilla is also making efforts to bring Lightning in line with current CalDAV standards. It works fairly well as a client for Apple's Calendar Server software.

Answer (score 8):

There is plenty of calendar software for Linux. Depending of your needs and desktop environment that you use you can choose from:

- [KOrganizer](http://userbase.kde.org/KOrganizer) from KDE,
- [Evolution](http://projects.gnome.org/evolution/) if you prefer GNOME,
- Mozilla Thunderbird with Lightning addon if you want to be multiplatfrom,
- [Remind](http://www.roaringpenguin.com/products/remind) for console users,
- and `M-x calendar` and `~/.diary` if you are Emacs user... ;)

Comment: I appreciate the many options, but for me personally Thunderbird is the only real choice as I don't use KDE or Gnome.  @tim gave that answer first so he gets the check, but I upvoted you as you provided a great deal of info. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for a great list. Anyone googling this question will get some good leads.

Comment: Remind is a great console app. Upvoted.

Comment: Caveat of Evolution: does not do CardDAV.

Answer (score -1):

I strongly recommend you to use Mozilla Sunbird.

[Official website](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/calendar/sunbird/)

Comment: That isn't being maintained after the last release, so I'm going to use what's intended to replace it. Thanks!